# mdrr dataset in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

The `mdrr` dataset in `caret` package is a set of two objects; data.frame (`mdrrDescr`), and an ordinary factor (`mdrrClass`). when I try to run `View()` command for `mdrrClass` it shows a factor with zero entries. why is it like this? also how to create a factor like that ? I think it'll be better to understand the question if you just run these commands.

```
data(mdrr)
class(mdrrClass)
View(mdrrClass)
```

it says:

> "Showing 1 to 0 of 528 entries"

on the source pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on which version from Rstudio you have. In my case `View(mdrrClass)` shows me the structure of mdrrClass in the view pane as if you ran `dput(mddrClass)`.

You can replicate it with a simple example:

```
set.seed(1234)
ex <- as.factor(sample(1:2, 10, replace = T))
View(ex)
```

This shows me the dput structure and the values in the view pane.